# Как сделать, чтобы обработчик срабатывал постоянно?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Я использую метод `on()`, потому что элементы, которые слушают событие, должны так же слушать события на других элементах, поэтому `addEventListener` здесь не катит. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать, чтобы обработчик срабатывал постоянно?

Вот то, о чем я говорю — обработчик срабатывает, к сожалению, только два раза:

```
$('#wrapper').children().children().on("click", "div.listener", function(e) {
            $( "div.listener" ).css("display", "none");
            $( "#clicker" ).bind("click", function(e) {
                $( "div.listener" ).css("display", "block");
                })
        });
    $( "#clicker" ).bind("click", function(e) {
        $( "div.listener" ).trigger("click");
        });
```

Вот весь код целиком - можно запустить для наглядности:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Документ без названия</title>
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    var allFormBlocks = document.getElementsByClassName("formblock");
    var hiddenArr = $(allFormBlocks);
    hiddenArr.slice(1).hide();

    $("div.listener").css("color", "red");

    $('#wrapper').children().children().on("click", "div.listener", function(e) {
            $( "div.listener" ).css("display", "none");
            $( "#clicker" ).bind("click", function(e) {
                $( "div.listener" ).css("display", "block");
                })
        });
    $( "#clicker" ).bind("click", function(e) {
        $( "div.listener" ).trigger("click");
        });

    $('#button1').bind("click", function(e){//конец блока1 следующий раздел
                            $('#block1').hide();
                            $('#block2').show();
                            }); 


    $('#button2').bind("click", function(e){//конец блока2 следующий раздел
                            $('#block2').hide();
                            $('#block3').show();
                            });

    $('#button3').bind("click", function(e){//конец блока2 предыдущий раздел
                                $('#block2').hide();
                                $('#block1').show();
                                }); 
    $('#button4').bind("click", function(e){//конец блока3 предыдущий раздел
                                $('#block3').hide();
                                $('#block2').show();
                                });                                 
});



</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="testform">
        <form method="POST" name="form">

                <div class="formblock" id="block1">
                    <h1>Это блок №1</h1>
                    <div>
                    <p><label><input id="clicker"  type="checkbox" name="npo" value="0">скрыть некоторые элементы<label></p>
                    </div>
                    <div>DIV блока №1</div>
                    <div class="listener">Это тоже DIV блока №1</div>
                    <div>и это тоже DIV блока №1</div>
                    <button type="button" id="button1">следующий раздел</button>
                </div>
                <div class="formblock" id="block2">
                    <h1>Это блок №2</h1>
                    <div>DIV блока №2</div>
                    <div class="listener">Это тоже DIV блока №2</div>
                    <div>и это тоже DIV блока №2</div>
                    <button type="button" id="button2">следующий раздел</button></br>
                    <button type="button" id="button3">предыдущий раздел</button>           
                </div>
                <div class="formblock" id="block3">
                    <h1>Это блок №3</h1>
                    <div>DIV блока №3</div>
                    <div class="listener">Это тоже DIV блока №3</div>
                    <div>и это тоже DIV блока №3</div>  
                    <button type="button" id="button4">предыдущий раздел</button>
                </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: не понимаю смысл `children().children()`, если в методе `on()` указан селектор

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Если коротко - то замените на :

```
$('#wrapper').children().children().on("click", "div.listener", function (e) {
    $("div.listener").toggle();
});
$("#clicker").bind("click", function (e) {
    $("div.listener").trigger("click");
});
```

Вы же в следующих частях кода используете функции `show` и `hide` так почему подобное не примените к скрытию некоторых элементов?)